# Copy input value after page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get the text value from the SOURCE to the TARGET,after the page fully loaded?

SOURCE

```
<input id="gclid_field">
```

TARGET

```
<input id="gclid_form">
```

SCRIPT

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
document.getElementById('gclid_field').value
document.getElementById('gclid_form').setAttribute('value');

})
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  const InputValue = document.getElementById('gclid_field').value;
  const InputTarget = document.getElementById('gclid_form');
  InputTarget.value = InputValue;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

better to store value first, then set value directly, not from setAttribute:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    let inputValue = document.getElementById('gclid_field').value;
    document.getElementById('gclid_form').value = inputValue;
});
```